# com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException in Quickbooks

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

When I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Name = 'ABC'
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException:
ERROR CODE:3202, ERROR MESSAGE:message=BadRequest;statusCode=400;error detail: null;
```

I am not able to get data from quickbooks as I am using intuit third party API to integrate my project with quickbooks.

Any one had an idea over this and what to do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Please provide the exact request url within the answer.

Comment: What is the base url you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Query string should be URL encoded.

Ex - `https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1222949965/query?query=select+*+from+Account+where+Name%3D%27Insurance%27`

Are you using IPP's JAVA devkit ?

Devkit code -

```
String query = "select * from Account where Name='Insurance'";
service.executeQuery(query);
```

Thanks

Comment: I am using the same devkit code as you are suggesting but still getting the same error.Please have a look at the link below as i had wrote my method code on this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278935/com-intuit-ipp-exception-fmsexception-in-quickbooks-part-2

Comment: @Minimul : Please have a look at the link below as i had wrote my method code on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278935/com-intuit-ipp-exception-fmsexception-in-quickbooks-part-2

Comment: @nimisha shrivastava : there are many URL's , i am not getting for which base url are you saying.